# Is $(xy-1)$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I learnd that the maximal ideals in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ have the form $(x-z_1, y-z_2)$ by the Nullstellensatz. But if we set $I=(xy-1)$ then $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x,1/x]$ which is in my opinion a field, thus $(xy-1)$ is maximal. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Please improve your formatting. See the edit help on how to write formulas.

Comment: @YACP: Power series rings are local. Besides, $XY-1$ is a unit in $C[[X,Y]]$.

Answer (score 11):

Since $xy-1=x(y+1)-(x+1)$, we can see that $(xy-1)\subsetneq (x+1,y+1)$.

The containment is proper since in the left-hand side, you cannot have elements with degree of $y$ less than 1, but in the right hand side, you can get elements with no $y$'s.

Comment: Yes, the hyperbola is not just the point $(-1,-1)$ ;). You can avoid degree arguments as follows: $(xy-1)$ lies in two *different* maximal ideals $(x \pm 1, y \pm 1)$, hence cannot be maximal.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Nice! Degrees are really simple, and I'm not sure why they are undesirable, but the different maximal ideal thing is definitely another excellent way to see that!

Answer (score 10):

$\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$ is not a field, in fact its spectrum is the pointed affine line, in particular more than just a point. For example, $x+1$ is not invertible. In fact, the group of units of $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$ is $\mathbb{C}^* \cdot \langle x \rangle$.

Comment: Nice one, this last remark was probably exactly what the OP was missing.

Comment: is it an integral domain?

Comment: Sure, it's a localization of a PID, hence a PID even.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal $(\rm XY - 1)$ describes a curve if you draw it and over $\mathbb C$, maximal ideals describe points.

At a technical level, the answer of Martin is right.